# How to declare a result into a string with proper format using variables?

Tags: c#

I can't seem to wrap my head around the feedback on my code.

> No result variable used. Use this variable to store your message + vacation type + group size.

I'm still new at learning the terms so when I worked on this assignment I was more focused on getting the result than understanding certain requirements. As the title suggests, I'm trying to figure out how to declare my result as a `string`.

How can I achieve that with correct sentence formatting using variables?

**Here is my code for reference**

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("What kind of trip would you like to go on, musical, tropical,"
                   + "or adventurous?");
    string vacationType = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("How many are in your group? ");
    int groupSize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    string vacationDest = "";
    string travelSugg = "";

    switch (vacationType)
    {
        case "tropical":
            vacationDest = "a beach vacation in Mexico";
            break;
        case "musical":
            vacationDest = "New Orleans";
            break;
        case "adventurous":
            vacationDest = "white water rafting the Grand Canyon";
            break;
    }

    if (groupSize <= 2)
        travelSugg = "first class";
    else if (groupSize > 2 && groupSize < 6)
        travelSugg = "helicopter";
    else
        travelSugg = "charter flight";

    Console.WriteLine("Since youre a group of " + groupSize
        + " going on a " + vacationType + " vacation, you should take a "
        + travelSugg + " to " + vacationDest);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Did you consider asking whomever provided this "feedback"?  Surely *they* will know what they meant better than we would.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but looks like all you need to do is something like `string result = "Since you're a group of " + groupSize + ......;` and then `Console.WriteLine(result);`. That being said, you should definitely confirm this with your instructor as @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp suggested.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed thanks for your comment, do you mean replacing  Console.WriteLine("Since youre a group of " + groupSize
            + " going on a " + vacationType + " vacation, you should take a "
            + travelSugg + " to " + vacationDest );
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed you were right. My problem was I was looking too much into the question, and not the obvious. thank you for helping me

Comment: I’m guessing you need to extract some of your logic to a separate method. Otherwise the notion of a “result” does make much sense (your main only returns void). Perhaps they wants you to learn how to define a custom class or struct to hold the result rather than working with a bunch of strings.

Comment: Seems like you just need to store the result to a variable, so instead of using `Console.WriteLine("blahblahblah" + blah)` you store `"blahblahblah" + blah` into a variable and use `Console.Writeline(yourVariable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, instead of

```
Console.WriteLine("Since youre a group of " + groupSize
        + " going on a " + vacationType + " vacation, you should take a "
        + travelSugg + " to " + vacationDest );
```

you can do

```
var resultString = "Since youre a group of " + groupSize
        + " going on a " + vacationType + " vacation, you should take a "
        + travelSugg + " to " + vacationDest;

Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You are correct. My problem was I was looking too much into the question and the output of the code instead of the formatting requirements for it.

Answer (score 1):

A proper way to insert values into a string variable is to use `String.Format()`. As you can see in the code below, it is easier to read. What you are doing is first *building* your sentence with curved brackets and numbers *for positioning* and then formatting that sentence with the values you want to add into your sentence.

```cs
string sentence = "Since you're a group of {0} going on a {1} vacation, you should take a {2} to {3}";
string output = string.Format(sentence, groupSize, vacationType, travelSugg, vacationDest);

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Another solution I can provide to you is this one, which I think is the easiest to manipulate. In this one, you can literally just add the variable names you need at the position needed directly in the sentence.

> Note that you need to add the dollar sign before the string `$""` to allow you to write variables in it.

```cs
string sentence = $"Since you're a group of {groupSize} going on a {vacationType} vacation, you should take a {travelSugg} to {vacationDest}";

Console.WriteLine(sentence);
```

---

I recommend that you name your variables the best way possible without exagerating so that others can understand in a blink of an eye what is this variable containing. When using the second format solution, it would be easier to read something more like `... you should take a {travelSuggestion} to {travelDestination}` don't you think?

To know more about the `String.Format()` method, I am referring you to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8) provided by Microsoft. I'm sure you will find it interesting.